# No mapping for GET /bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

I have configured an folder for images in my spring boot project, after that my project doesn't mapping my boostrap styles.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Value("${demo.ruta.imagenes}")
    private String rutaImagenes;

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/logos/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + rutaImagenes);
    }

}
```

My folder resources:

[image]

In my html files I get my styles:

In header:

```
<link th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/jumbotron.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<link th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https:/ /use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Before body:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this method and bootstrap get mapping.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when i added bootstrap to my project, that problem because i'm using `spring-security` configuration the security policy is block the bootstrap resource and i have fixed with add security configuration in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
extended class, like the following code

```
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Web resource
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/css/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/fonts/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/js/**");
    }
}
```

i follow this step from this site https://www.hellojava.com/a/47153.html if you want more.

that solve my problem and i hope you too